# Msmq and sgen for xmlserialization utter failure

Tags: .net, vb.net, xml-serialization, msmq, xmlserializer

I 've been banging my head with this to to avail. Any ideas are much welcome!

I have a client/listener application in vb.net using MSMQ and it works 100% fine when I do not use sgen.exe to generate the serializations on compile time.

When using sgen, it fails on the listener part.

```
        qOrders.Formatter = New XmlMessageFormatter(New Type() {GetType(InfoMessage)})

        m = qOrders.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult)
```

It bombs on m. m.Body has the error `"Cannot deserialize the message passed as an argument. Cannot recognize the serialization format."` and the rest of the properties also have errors of not receiving a value.

The assembly is strong named and the App.XmlSerializers.dll is also signed correctly. I know the dll is used because I can't delete it while the program is running.

The InfoMessage class is a simple public class with 3 public string members. Inspecting the dll with Reflector, I do see that sgen has generated an InfoMessageSerializer class.

The problem is not on the client side because I delete the dll and run the listener, it works as usual.

So, what could be wrong here? :o

Thanks,

John

Edit: Link to Listener source: http://pastebin.com/TqWfLVJ0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [design limitation](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94449/sgen-on-the-server) of `sgen` output.  This limitation was [never removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> These generated assemblies cannot be used on the server side of a Web service. This tool is only for Web service clients and manual serialization scenarios.

Basically, you are not expected to run `sgen` to make the server side of a web service faster, because `XmlSerializer` startup time is not a crucial factor of its performance (in contrast with some types of clients).

Of course, `sgen` *can* be used on the server side in a non-web service scenario, as long as you do not pass any `XmlAttributeOverrides` to the constructor of `XmlSerializer`.

With MSMQ, there is a choice of binary and XML serialization, and your code chooses the latter here:

```
qOrders.Formatter = New XmlMessageFormatter(New Type() {GetType(InfoMessage)})
```

So let's have a look at how `MessageQueue` creates an `XmlSerializer`.  The following is a method of `XmlMessageFormatter` taken from `System.Messaging.dll`, .NET 4.0.  Its .NET 2.0 counterpart is similar.

```
private void CreateTargetSerializerTable()
{
  if (!this.typeNamesAdded)
  {
    for (int index = 0; index < this.targetTypeNames.Length; ++index)
    {
      Type type = Type.GetType(this.targetTypeNames[index], true);
      if (type != (Type) null)
        this.targetSerializerTable[(object) type]
          = (object)new XmlSerializer(type);
    }
    this.typeNamesAdded = true;
  }
  if (!this.typesAdded)
  {
    for (int index = 0; index < this.targetTypes.Length; ++index)
      this.targetSerializerTable[(object) this.targetTypes[index]] 
        = (object)new XmlSerializer(this.targetTypes[index]);
    this.typesAdded = true;
  }
  if (this.targetSerializerTable.Count == 0)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Res.GetString("TypeListMissing"));
}
```

As you can see, MSMQ does not supply `XmlAttributeOverrides`, unlike web services server side code in the framework.  Still, there are other people who [have trouble](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/xmlmessageserializer-sgen-serialization-assembly-t3727491.html) with combining XmlMessageFormatter and `sgen`.

My guess is that `sgen` can still be made to work with MSMQ because MSMQ does not use `XmlAttributeOverrides`, but you will have to make sure that you are not using the `proxytypes` command line option, and that you are still moving way outside of what Microsoft ever tested.

I would advise looking at these possibilities:

- Avoid using `sgen` with MSMQ.
- Avoid using `/proxytypes` option with `sgen`.
- Disable `SGenUseProxyTypes` in case you invoke `sgen` from your project file ([look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629394.aspx) to see how).
- Look at using binary serialization with MSMQ.
- Pay close attention to what types you are sending through the queue on the client side.

Comment: Interesting! One question though: Both documents discuss about Web Services - and I 'm not doing anything related to a web service, so how does it apply? In fact, it 's just a bare-bones PoC for MSMQ communication (scaled down from the actual app to pinpoint the problem).

Comment: @johnjohn - Answer expanded.  BTW if your question contained more code, especially who and how instantiates `XmlSerializer`, that would make it a better question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have updated with a link to the Listener code - it bombs on the qOrders_ReceiveCompleted method (which contains the code in the question). It does not use XmlAttributeOverrides at all.